# Send 1 Million records data to external system using batch class

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, callout

I am trying to send the data to external system from batch class.. Where data include 1 million records.. I wrote below batch class.

In batch class I am making callout to the external system and sending the data in wrapper format to external system.

**Main Question :**

1. Code works for million records ?
2. Can JSON string (using wrapper) can we send million data to external system any limitations I might face with below code ?
3. Data will be sent everyday night

Batch Class:

```
global class AccountHttpBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    
    global String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account';
        global List<Account> lstAccountData; 
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) { 
        system.debug('scope'+scope);
        String endpoint;  
        String status;
      
       List<Error_Log__c> errorLogLst = new List<Error_Log__c>(); 
        sendAccountWrapper op;
        for(Account cont : scope){
       
            op = new sendAccountWrapper();
            op.AccountName = cont.Name;
            op.Industry = cont.Industry;
            op.NumberofEmployees = cont.NumberOfEmployees;
            op.Phone = cont.Phone;
            op.Rating = cont.Rating;
            op.Type = cont.Type;
        }
        
        String Outputget = JSON.serialize(op); 
        system.debug('Outputget'+Outputget);
        try {                  
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            Http http = new Http();
            
            endpoint = 'http://my.foo.bar/service';
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'header');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setBody(Outputget);
            res = http.send(req);
            String sJson = res.getBody();
            System.debug('Str:' + res.getBody());
            if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
                status = 'SUCCESS';
            }else{
                Error_Log__c error = new Error_Log__c();
                error.AccountId__c = '';
                error.Error_Message__c = res.getBody();
                error.Status__c = res.getStatus(); 
                 rrorLogLst.add(error);
                insert errorLogLst;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {         
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'Line no:' + e.getLineNumber() );           
        }
    }   
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Wrapper :

```
public class sendAccountWrapper {

    public string AccountName;
    public string Phone;
    public string Type;
    public string Rating;
    public Integer NumberofEmployees;
    public string Industry;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  You got a bunch of downvotes because it doesn't look as if you demonstrated any research. Please use [edit] to amend your question

Comment: It looks like your code is unifinished? There are commented bits and you are overwriting the value of `op` without adding it to a `List`

Comment: @fred this is a sample code.. I removed the commented part may be it might be clear to you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions, assuming you fix the issues with your sample code:

1. The code will work for 1 million records. Using the maximum batch size of 2000, your code will run 500 times and do 500 callouts to your external system.
2. You won't be able to send 1 million records in one go, no. The maximum batch size is 2000.
3. You can schedule the batch to run every night using a separate scheduler class in Apex.

Comment: Thank you @fred